# Error creating config section handler

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, spring.net

I have a MVC Project which uses Simple Injector for DI.  I have a section in my web config as below:

```
  <bar>
    <foo>
      <add key="my.key" value="my.value" />
      <add key="my.key2" value="my.value2" />
    </foo>
  </bar>
```

At the top of my web config file then I have added this section and the Code File it relates to in my service layer as below:

```
  <configSections>
    <section name="bar" type="MVCProj.Service.Services.MyConfigurationSection, MVCProj.Service, Culture=neutral" />
  </configSections>
```

Withing Simple Injector Registration class then in my Service Layer in my RegisterServices method I have the following:

```
  public static void RegisterServices(Container container)
    {
        container.RegisterSingle(() => ((MyConfigurationSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("bar")));

    }
```

In the class I use MyConfigurationSection I have the following:

```
private readonly MyConfigurationSection _myConfigSection;

public MyService(MyConfigurationSection myConfigSection)
{
    _myConfigSection = myConfigSection;
}
```

For reference then MyConfigurationSection class is as below:

```
public class MyConfigurationSection : ConfigurationSection
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("foo", IsRequired = true)]
    public KeyValueConfigurationCollection Foo
    {
        get { return (KeyValueConfigurationCollection)this["foo"]; }
    }
}
```

And the service that is injection into MyService class is used as below:

```
    var configuration = _myConfigSection.Foo.AllKeys.ToDictionary(
        key => key,
        key => _configurationSection.Foo[key].Value);
```

This is working as expected and when I run the solution and set a break on `var configuration` I can see values returned from web.config as expected.

However I am now trying to copy the same functionality with another project however it uses Spring.NET for DI Framework.  I am a relative noob with Spring so I am having some difficulty with this.

I have added the same as I done with MVC Project to WebConfig.

Within the Service Layer the MyService class I now have added the following:

```
public class MyService : IMyService
    {
        public MyConfigurationSection ConfigSection;

            var configuration = ConfigSection.Foo.AllKeys.ToDictionary(
                key => key,
                key => ConfigSection.Foo[key].Value);

   // rest of class removed for brevity
```

I then have a spring-Service xml at the service layer which I attempted to wire up as below:

```
 <object id="myConfigSection" type="OtherProj.Core.Service.MyConfigurationSection, OtherProj.Core">
  </object>

  <object id="myService" type="OtherProj.Core.Service.MyService, OtherProj.Core">
    <property name="ConfigSection" ref="myConfigSection" />
  </object>
```

In the other project before `var configuration` I attempted calling `ConfigurationManager.GetSection("bar");`  but when I run the project and attempt to hit MyService I am getting an Exception saying :

*"An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for bar: Could not load file or assembly 'OtherProj.Core.Service, Culture=neutral' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. (D:\Full Path to file\web.config line 7)"*

Am I missing something in how this Dependency should be wired up with Spring?

Comment: Is the `OtherProj.Core.Service` dll in the bin directory?

Comment: I've removed the SimpleInjector tag as this is not a question for SimpleInjector